# Dynamic has_many class_name using polymorphic reference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphism

I am trying to associate a polymorphic model (in this case `Product`) to a dynamic class name (either `StoreOnePurchase` or `StoreTwoPurchase`) based on the `store_type` polymorphic reference column on the `products` table.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store, polymorphic: true
  has_many :purchases, class_name: (StoreOnePurchase|StoreTwoPurchase)
end

class StoreOne < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, as: :store
  has_many :purchases, through: :products
end

class StoreOnePurchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end

class StoreTwo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products, as: :store
  has_many :purchases, through: :products
end

class StoreTwoPurchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
end
```

`StoreOnePurchase` and `StoreTwoPurchase` have to be separate models because they contain very different table structure, as does `StoreOne` and `StoreTwo`.

I am aware that introducing a HABTM relationship could solve this like this:

```
class ProductPurchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :purchase, polymorphic: true
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :store, polymorphic: true
  has_many :product_purchases
end

class StoreOnePurchase < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :product_purchase, as: :purchase
  delegate :product, to: :product_purchase
end
```

However I am interested to see if it is possible without an extra table?

Comment: are you looking for STI ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting question. But, unfortunately, it is impossible without an extra table, because there is no polymorphic `has_many` association. Rails won't be able to determine type of the `Product.purchases` (has_many) dynamically the same way it does it for `Product.store` (belongs_to). Because there's no `purchases_type` column in `Product` and no support of any dynamically-resolved association types in `has_many`. You can do some trick like the following:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  class DynamicStoreClass
     def to_s
        #return 'StoreOnePurchase' or 'StoreTwoPurchase'
     end
  end      
  belongs_to :store, polymorphic: true
  has_many :purchases, class_name: DynamicStoreClass
end
```

It will not throw an error, but it is useless, since it will call DynamicStoreClass.to_s only once, before instantiating the products.

You can also override `ActiveRecord::Associations::association` to support polymorphic types in your class, but it is reinventing the Rails.

I would rather change the database schema.

Comment: Excellent answer, and nice solution, but yes, I share your concern. Simply put I am expecting the polymorphic association to `store` to have too much responsibility.